# How to get date from a string without formatting?

Tags: java, android, date, date-parsing, java.util.date

I have a

```
String s = "2020-02-22"`;
```

and I want to change it to `Date` so I can store it in my database which has has a column that does not accept anything but `Date`.

I tried using the `LocalDate` class but it's in API 26.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried java.util.Date?

Comment: @GauthamM yes I tried it with simpleDateFormat but it makes formatted date ,but I want my date to be just as my string

Comment: Are you saying that you want the date to be stored in `yyyy-MM-dd` format in the database as well?

Comment: @GauthamM no I want it to be stored like the string "2020-02-22"

Comment: @GauthamM the format adds other information which I don't want

Comment: Which database are you using? Since the database stores this field as a `date` and not as a `string`, it would be stored in that way only. While retrieving the data from database you can convert it back to the desired `string` format using `SimpleDataFormat`

Comment: `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , LocalDate.parse( "2020-02-22" ) ) ;`

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you fetch the date from database and pass it to the below method:

```java
public String formatDate(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat ff = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");           
    return ff.format(date);
}
```

**EDIT :** based on input from [Basil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque), you could try [Android Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to make use of Java 8+ functionality without the need of minimum API level. This would allow the use of `LocalDate` instead of the old `java.util.Date` class.
Using `LocalDate` you could parse a string to date as:

```java
public LocalDate getDate(String dateString) {
    return LocalDate.parse(dateString);
}
```

Comment: FYI: Those terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting those legacy classes in 2021 is poor advice.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, but from the question, it seems like an older version is being used.

Comment: The latest Android tooling brings most of the *java.time* functionality to older versions of Android via “API desugaring”.

Comment: @BasilBourque Updated the answer based on comment